# What are the AppName, AppPublisher and AppVersion header values for a WSE 2012 R2 WebApi call?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to query my Server 2012 Essentials R2 server to determine the most recent Client Backup time for a given Device, so I can display nag screens at signon for forgetful users. (They're on laptops, so I can't depend on the machine being available during the automatic window.)

The closest thing in the way of documentation I've been able to find is this: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713757.aspx)

```
GET services/builtin/DeviceManagement.svc/devices/index/{index}/count/{count}
```

But it requires a preceding call to get the token: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713753.aspx)

```
GET https://www.contoso.com/services/builtin/session.svc/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Host: servername
Authorization: Basic VXNlcjpQYXNzd29yZCE=
AppName: Sample App Name
AppPublisher: publisher
AppVersion: 1.0
```

Does anyone know what the values for those last three headers should be—or how to discover them—for a standard WSE 2012 R2 installation? The documentation provides no assistance here.

Or if someone knows a better way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working. The code is below.

As it turns out, the value of the AppName header is irrelevant—it can be any string, but it can't be empty.

I already knew it couldn't be empty from a look at the WSE source in `Wssg.WebApi.Framework` in the GAC, but the code is decoupled to the point that it's next to impossible to find out what process picks up the the `RemoteConnectionClientInfo` object once it gets dropped into the HTTP session.

The part that was misleading me was—go figure—the documentation itself.

There's a bang (`!`) after the password on the [Authentication page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713753.aspx), suggesting that it should trail the actual password prior to encoding. This was why I was getting an authentication error, which in turn I was (mistakenly) attributing to the statement in the documentation: "*Add Appname, Apppublisher, and Appversion values in HTTP header fields. These values are also required to log on."*

So once I cleared all that up, I sailed right in.

And there are other errors in the documentation. On the [Devices page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713757.aspx) we are told that the `Host` header should be set to the domain name, and that a `Content-Length` header should be added.

These are both incorrect. The `Host` header should be the server's hostname and there should be no `Content-Length` header (that's a response header, not a request header).

AND...! After all this, I find that the Device info returned doesn't contain the most recent backup time. I'll have to dig further for that. But at least now I can connect.

So Microsoft's incomplete, inaccurate and sloppy documentation has cost me a day's work. Hopefully somebody else can use this and avoid the pain I went through.

```
Module Main
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim aCredentials() As Byte

    Dim _
      oAuthenticateUri,
      oDeviceListUri As Uri

    Dim _
      sCanary,
      sCookie,
      sDevices As String

    aCredentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}")

    Using oClient As New HttpClient
      oAuthenticateUri = New Uri($"https://{HOST}/services/builtin/session.svc/login")
      oDeviceListUri = New Uri($"https://{HOST}/services/builtin/devicemanagement.svc/devices/index/0/count/99")

      oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"))
      oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(aCredentials))
      oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = HOST
      oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AppPublisher", String.Empty)
      oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AppVersion", String.Empty)
      oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AppName", "None")

      Using oAuthenticateResponse As HttpResponseMessage = oClient.GetAsync(oAuthenticateUri).Result
        If oAuthenticateResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
          sCanary = oAuthenticateResponse.Headers.Single(Function(Pair) Pair.Key = CANARY_HEADER).Value(0)
          sCookie = Split(oAuthenticateResponse.Headers.Single(Function(Pair) Pair.Key = COOKIE_HEADER).Value(0), ";")(0)

          oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear()
          oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = HOST
          oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(CANARY_HEADER, sCanary)
          oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(COOKIE_HEADER, sCookie)

          Using oDeviceListResponse As HttpResponseMessage = oClient.GetAsync(oDeviceListUri).Result
            If oDeviceListResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
              sDevices = oDeviceListResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result
            Else
              Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", oDeviceListResponse.StatusCode, oDeviceListResponse.ReasonPhrase)
            End If
          End Using
        Else
          Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", oAuthenticateResponse.StatusCode, oAuthenticateResponse.ReasonPhrase)
        End If
      End Using
    End Using
  End Sub



  Private Const CANARY_HEADER As String = "Canary"
  Private Const COOKIE_HEADER As String = "Set-Cookie"
  Private Const USERNAME As String = "domain.admin"
  Private Const PASSWORD As String = "admin.password"
  Private Const HOST As String = "server"
End Module
```